# Can the imprisoned Egypt presidential candidate Ahmed Konsowa be on the ballot? What is the law applying to him?

Tags: election, presidential-election, egypt

I found a [tweet](https://twitter.com/POMED/status/961974317755043840) by POMED (Project on Middle East Democracy) that shares an image whose title is:

> Dropping like flies: Sisi's purge of potential candidates in Egypt's presidential "election":

The full image contains a description on how *real* candidates have been banned from competing in the presidential election that is going to be hold on March 26-28:

> [image]
>
> <sub>(click to see it full size)</sub>

I was specially surprised by this one:

> Ahmed Konsowa ARMY COLONEL. Konsawa declared his intention to run November 30, 2017. Subsequently, he was detained for 15 days and sentenced to six years in prison by a military court for announcing his candidacy in uniform—though Sisi did the same in 2014.

I found some news like [Egyptian army officer jailed after announcing presidential candidacy: lawyer, family](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-egypt-politics/egyptian-army-officer-jailed-after-announcing-presidential-candidacy-lawyer-family-idUSKBN1ED2EL) and [Wife of Armed Forces officer and presidential hopeful Konsowa says he is being ‘treated well’ in detention](https://www.madamasr.com/en/2017/12/03/news/u/wife-of-armed-forces-officer-and-presidential-hopeful-konsowa-says-he-is-being-treated-well-in-detention/) and found some kind of confirmation on that:

> He now faces charges of publishing a video in which he espoused his political views and violating military code and procedure.

Then it states:

> According to Konsowa, he has attempted to resign from his military post countless times since March 2014 — a decision he said was spurred by President Abdel Fattah al-Sisi’s announcement of his candidacy in the 2014 presidential elections — but has been impeded by what he called bureaucratic red tape.

All in all, it looks like he was imprisoned for publishing political views on Facebook while being a member of the army. However, he states that this is the exact same thing that the current president [Abdel Fattah el-Sisi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdel_Fattah_el-Sisi) did on 2014, since he was the General Commander of the Armed Forces when he ran for presidency.

So: did Konsowa really violate any law from the Army? Did el-Sisi also violate that?

Also: can he be on the ballot? What is the law applying here?

Comment: There is this universal human law: what's permitted a General (especially a winning one), isn't permitted to a Colonel.

Comment: The final question is one of law, but the bulk of the text seems devoted to the politics which moot the law question. Perhaps it is better phrased as "will Konsowa be on the ballot?" Which will be definitively answerable in due time, and pretty confidently guessed now. Or "Is there any example of rule of law in Egypt?" which probably would turn up something.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt thanks for your comment. You are right! I tried to improve the title and the final questions.

Comment: You are on topic here, but questions about law are probably more likely to get good answers at law.se.